# Unable to install latest R version on Ubuntu 18.04 linux

Tags: r, linux, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I want to be able to install the latest stable R release for Ubuntu 18.04, I had the ubuntu version installed and so I removed it and then followed several guides like in [this](https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-01-29/installing-r-r-packages-e-g-tidyverse-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu-linux/) link.

No matter what I do I get the following output when I issue a `sudo apt-get install r-base`:

```
sudo apt install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.1-3disco) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.1-3disco) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be the problem here, including: which PPAs you have configured; did you do `apt update` after adding any new PPAs; did any previous package not complete installing/configuring; and likely more. I think you may get a better response on https://askubuntu.com/, though, as this question is entirely about PPAs and installation of external packages, not about R itself.

Comment: ok that makes sense - I posted the same question on askubuntu.com https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188794/unable-to-install-latest-r-version-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux

Comment: I see that (maybe) you have solved your problem, since you asked some R questions later. Could you provide your solution or close the question?